# Как округлить число либо до ближайшей половины, либо до ближайшего целого числа?

Tags: javascript, округление

Как округлить, например, число 2,35 до 2,5 и число 3,76 до 4 при помощи JS? Нужна динамическая система, которая могла бы округлять число до ближайшей половины, либо до целого числа.

Comment: Обратите внимание на вариант Андрея, он работает со всем диапазоном чисел и куда более лаконичный. Мой вариант сложнее и работает только с диапазоном N >= 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из того как я понял поставленную задачу (только для положительных чисел больше либо равных 1):

```js
function numRound(num) {
    let d = Math.floor(num),
      i = num%d;
    return i < .25 ? d : (i < .75 ? d + .5 : d + 1);
}

console.log(numRound(2));    // 2
console.log(numRound(2.01)); // 2
console.log(numRound(2.24)); // 2
console.log(numRound(2.25)); // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.5));  // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.74)); // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.75)); // 3
console.log(numRound(2.99)); // 3
console.log(numRound(3));    // 3
```

Answer (score 9):

1) Умножить на 2.
2) Округлить до ближайшего целого.
3) Разделить на 2.

```js
function numRound(num) {
    return Math.round(num * 2) / 2;
}

console.log(numRound(2));    // 2
console.log(numRound(2.01)); // 2
console.log(numRound(2.24)); // 2
console.log(numRound(2.25)); // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.5));  // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.74)); // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.75)); // 3
console.log(numRound(2.99)); // 3
console.log(numRound(-1.01));// -1
console.log(numRound(-1.26));// -1.5
console.log(numRound(-1.74));// -1.5
console.log(numRound(-1.76));// -2
console.log(numRound(-0.26));// -0.5
```

Можно сделать универсальную функцию, в которую передавать точность:

```js
function numRound(num, precision) {
    return Math.round(num / precision) * precision;
}

console.log(numRound(2, 0.5));    // 2
console.log(numRound(2.31, 0.5)); // 2.5
console.log(numRound(2.24, 0.2)); // 2.2
console.log(numRound(2.51, 0.2)); // 2.6
console.log(numRound(153, 2));    // 154
console.log(numRound(170, 50));   // 150
console.log(numRound(206, 10));   // 210
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `Math.round`. Если после применения оного результат меньше исходного, то значит к результату надо прибавить 0.5. Для чисел от N.5 `Math.round` выдаст целое число

Comment: `Math.round(2.17) // 2` - получается нужно 2.5, так как 2 < 2.17, а должно быть 2.

Comment: @MedvedevDev  ну я так понял что ему надо от N.00001 до N.4999999 округлять до половины. в ином случае расплывается грань когда нужно в меньшую сторону округлять а когда до N.5

Comment: На сколько я понял ему требуется N.01 - N.24 округлять до N; N.25 - N.74 округлять до N.5; N.75 - N.99 округлять до N+1; Думаю требуются пояснения от автора.